# I have a DELL leap top from 2015: should I buy a new one or upgrade?

Tags: laptop

I have a DELL leap top Inspiron 15 3000 Series that I bought to years ago. 
The RAM memory is 8 GB, The processor model is intel(R)core(TM) iS-4210u cpu@ 1.706GHz 1.60 Ghz.
Me main use of this PC is for map making with [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) software. Some of maps have a lot of details and I need to make them with 1300 dpi. It  can take up to ten mints to make this map and I need to close another software. 
I want me PC to work faster and I was wandering what is the best way: to upgrade or to buy a new one?
The maps take a lot of memory space so I was thinking to upgrade to 1,000 GB SSD drive, to upgrade me processor and to ask the technicians to clean the hardware form dust and replace the fan into a new one.

Comment: Upgrading processors in laptops is mostly not possible as the CPUs are embedded in the motherboard and don't use a socket. If you want a new CPU, just buy a new laptop that has your required specs.

Comment: Thanks, is the SSD driver is an improvement? If so I will upgrade and whit some time before buying a new one

Comment: Yes, the SSD is an improvement. However, I do not recommend upgrading only the storage drive if you are having bad performance, in which case you should buy a new laptop/desktop. Otherwise, just upgrade to an SSD.

Comment: Unless you're making these maps all day long, I wouldn't care about 10 minutes and leave the laptop as it is. If you want to upgrade anyway, I would look into more main memory (if supported by the laptop), because you mentioned closing other applications to run the map maker.